# RTNETLINK answers: file exists - configure interface

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualbox, network-bridge

Forgive the newbie question.

I am trying to setup `eth1` in `interfaces`:

[image]

however, I am getting: `RTNETLINK answers: file exists`

here are the results of `ifconfig`:

[image]

**what am i doing wrong?**

Answer (score 8):

If you had been manually setting a [temporary configuration](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration), e.g by doing something like `sudo ifconfig eth0 10.0.0.100 netmask 255.255.255.0`, you should clear that up first:

```bash
sudo ip addr flush eth0
```

Now you can try again:

```bash
sudo ip link set eth0 up
```

Answer (score 3):

Manual methods are unlikely to work correctly if Network Manager is installed and running. If it is installed, it is advisable to set the details there:  [image]

If you have removed Network Manager, your interfaces file will also need a gateway and DNS nameservers:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.117
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1  #or whatever your router address is
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
```

Then get the system to re-read and use the changes:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```

Check:

```
ping -c3 www.google.com
```

Comment: thanks so much! what is the difference between setting these through /etc/..interfaces    vs this http://i.stack.imgur.com/j4OPN.png ??

Comment: The difference is that /etc/network/interfaces is designed for manual methods; servers, etc. and Network Manager is designed for the everyday desktop and laptop user. There is a mechanism in NM designed to use the interfaces file if it's filled in, but, in my experience, it's hit and miss. If you have NM installed, I strongly recommend you use that method. Of course, if you are curious, you can try first one and then the other and see what works best for you.

Comment: thanks!! so how do i know from which method the settings are being used?

Comment: The way it's supposed to work is that NM does the work unless /etc/network/interfaces is filled in and then only if 'managed=false' is set in NetworkManager.conf. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html However, if BOTH are filled in, then I think it's anybody's guess what happens. That's why I recommend one or the other, not both. You may get some clues from the terminal: cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork  Are there many references to Network Manager? If so, I suspect it's doing all the work.

Comment: If `/etc/network/interfaces` does not exist and networkmanager is the only thing being use, what then? This isn't a ubuntu system but I am still curious :) **EDIT:** nevermind, removed some malformed `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*` files from trying to edit networkmanager using another program - it really it picky about what it uses, and seems to recreate files if it don't like them instead of doing a obvious error... Also for systems using the journal thing it seems to be `journalctl -xe | grep etwork` or `systemctl status network`

Comment: If it isn't an Ubuntu system, we don't know and we have no suggestions.